# SharePoint 2013 People Picker - Cant resolve names from a different domain

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have 2 AD domains - Contoso and ContosoDev , and ContosoDev Trusts Contoso

My SharePoint environment is installed in ContosoDev.   I want People Pickers in SharePoint to resolve names that live in AD in the Contoso domain.

I've set up a password for my web app on ContosoDev to query Contoso domain via stsadm.exe as follows:

```
  stsadm.exe -o setapppassword -pass@word1

  stsadm -o setproperty -url http://contosodev:80 -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:contoso.corp.com,contoso\bsmith,pass@word1"
```

after successfully executing this, my people picker in contosoDev still cant resolve any contoso names.   Is there another step that i need to take?

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found.

In my case, it was possible to set up a connection between ContosoDEV and Contoso.   The connection requires a username/password combination of a user who has permission to query the Contoso domain.

Step 1:  Set up a signing key 
stsadm.exe -o setapppassword -pass@word1

Step 2: Configure connection 
stsadm.exe -o setproperty -url http://xrpswdappmsp01:80 -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:Corp.net,contoso\bradF,pass@word1;domain:contoso.corp.net,contoso\BradF,pass@word1"

Step 3:  Repeat Step 2 for each web application in your farm that needs to see the other domain.

HTH.